# Copy and paste Excel data into Flex text box

Tags: apache-flex, excel

Our users want to copy and paste some rows from an Excel spreadsheet, or a chart generated in Excel, into a text box within a Flex application.

It would be ok for it not to be fully functional, like an ActiveX object, embedded in the flex app.  If it converted it to a static image, that would be fine.  But I don't know of any Flex component that supports this.

Comment: Is there anything in Flex which supports this?

Comment: Copying and pasting rows from an Excel spreadsheet into a Flex application.  As mentioned aboved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this can't be done.  What a shame.  Now I am sad.

Comment: Very constructive comment. Bravo!

Comment: Have you _seen_ the comments to the original question?  They are quite deliberately evasive.